# How to write help class for the below trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

```
trigger ActiveCountContactOnAccount on Contact (after INSERT, after UPDATE, after DELETE , after UNDELETE) {
Set <Id> accountIds = new Set <Id>();
List <Account> lstAccountsToUpdate = new List <Account>();
 if(Trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUnDelete){
    for(Contact con:trigger.new){
        accountIds.add(con.accountID);
    }
}else{
    for(Contact con:trigger.old){

        accountIds.add(con.accountID);        

    }
}
list<Account> lst = [SELECT Id,Name,Active_Contact_Count__c,(Select Id from Contacts where Status__c = 'Active') from Account where Id IN: accountIds];
for(Account acc:lst){
    Account accObj = new Account ();
    accObj = acc;
    accObj.Active_Contact_Count__c = acc.Contacts.size();
    lstAccountsToUpdate.add(accObj);
}
if(!lstAccountsToUpdate.isEmpty())
UPDATE lstAccountsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing that you tend to ask for a lot of help regarding unit testing, and most of your questions are closed as duplicates. Posting similar questions over and over isn't going to help you too much, and might eventually lead to the system barring you from asking further questions. The purpose of this site isn't to be a free coding service, but rather one that tries to help you become a better programmer/admin by helping you overcome specific problems. The key here is that we need to see that you've made an attempt to solve your own problem first, and that your question is very specific.

Comment: There are two trailhead modules that you should look at if you're truly stuck at how to start writing unit tests. [Unit testing on the lightning platform](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform) and [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing).